# Script that initiate a call using Skype For Business

Tags: c#, lync-client-sdk, skype-for-business

I'm trying to create a simple script that can initiate a call to a contact on **Skype For Businness**.

Actually, i'm trying to do it using the **Lync 2013 SDK in C#** but it don't seems to work. The function `LyncClient.ConversationManager.AddConversation()` just don't want to work and it launch a stupid exception : `Microsoft.Lync.Model.LyncClientException`. Of course, this exception isn't referenced on the microsoft doc...

There is almost two days i've past on it, if someone have a solution i'll be thanksfull !

Comment: I worked on severals solutions. I find out something : However is the way i try to obtain it, my **Conversation** object is always null...

Answer (score 0):

First off, make sure you have a client from the [LyncClient.GetClient()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.lync.model.lyncclient.getclient_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncctrsl.aspx).  Then check that the client is signed in. e.g. [client.State](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.lync.model.client.state_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncctrsl.aspx) == ClientState.SignedIn.

To make a new call you need to get the automation object from the Lync client.

`automation = LyncClient.GetAutomation()`

Then you use the [BeginStartConversation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.lync.model.extensibility.automation.beginstartconversation_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncclnt.aspx) / [EndStartConversation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh347650.aspx) to start the new call.
e.g.

```
var participantUri = new List<string> {"sip:{username}@{lyncdomain}"};
automation.EndStartConversation(automation.BeginStartConversation(AutomationModalities.Audio, participantUri, null, null, null))
```